# Mongoose relation not working both ways

Tags: express, mongoose, mean-stack

I can't get a relationship running between my Rides and Comments controller in my app (built using the yeoman angular-fullstack generator).

**Comment model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var CommentSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  comment: String,
  active: Boolean,
  ride: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ride' }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

**Ride model:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var RideSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  distance: String,
  climb: String,
  rating: String,
  active: Boolean,
  comments: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Ride', RideSchema);
```

Accessing /api/comments/ gives me a correct result, containing a related Ride:

```
{"_id":"54ce818f8c2889da58b01e19","name":"NAAM","comment":"COMMENT","ride":"54ce69647a78532057aa98e0","__v":0}]
```

Accessing /api/rides/ gives me the following result, without the corresponding Comments:

```
[{"_id":"54ce69647a78532057aa98e0","name":"Ride test ingevuld","distance":"4000","climb":"1200","rating":"1","__v":0,"comments":[]}]
```

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example from one of my projects:

```
exports.insertRoom = function(req, res) {
var id =  req.body.id;

var r =  req.body.room;
var room = new Room({name: r.name});

Floor.update(
    {_id : id},
    {
        $push: { rooms: room}
    },
    {upsert:true},
    function(floor, err)
    {
            res.sendStatus(200);
    }
);
```

};

Comment: It almost works.. except my ng-repeat does not update (refreshing updates the list containing comments). In my controller i have:
`exports.addCommentToRide = function(req, res) {

  var id = req.params.id;
  var c = req.body.comment;
  var comment = new Comment({name: c.name});

  Ride.update({_id : id}, { $push: { comments: comment} },
    {upsert:true},
    function(ride,err){
      return res.json(200, ride);
    }
  );
};`

Comment: Check in db if your data was saved properly. If it does, you must read again collection from the server to refresh data od keep this collection in your scope, and every success post, add t same data to your local array. Make sure you receive Rides with comments from te server, you can check it in 'Network' tab in google chrome inspector which shows u all your requests and responses from the server

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'am concerned it doesn't work like that. Your comments got it's ride, and your ride got it's comments. I think, you should remove

```
ride: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Ride' }
```

and keep comments inside ride collection.

```
comments: ['Comment']
```

It is more objective solution as it supposed to be in MONGO DB which was designed for objective(hierarchial) data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Maybe my controller isn't correct ($http.post('/api/comments', { name: 'NAAM', comment: 'COMMENT', ride: $scope.id});) ?

Comment: I would do it this way: 1. ride server controller  addCommentToRide with $push (read moongose $push) which would push comment object to ride object. Then add own server routing to this POST action. Then you can post your comment from angular via $http e.g. {comment:commentObject, rideId:yourRideId}